# No JFrame Title after exporting to JAR

Tags: eclipse, jar, export, frame, title

When running the JAVA app in Eclipse, the JFrame title is displayed, but when running the exported JAR file, there is no title showing on the frame.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
  f.setTitle("X: " + location.x + " , Y: " + location.y);
  recenterMouse();
}
public void init() {
  // add frame
  f = new JFrame("Muis Meet");
  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  f.setSize(screensizex, screensizey);
  f.getContentPane().add(this, FlowLayout.LEFT);
  f.setVisible(true);

  centerLocation.x = getWidth() / 2;
  centerLocation.y = getHeight() / 2;
  recenterMouse();
  addMouseListener(this);
  addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    MuisMeet muismeet = new MuisMeet();
    muismeet.init();
  }});
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
  recenterMouse();
  location.x = 0;
  location.y = 0;
  f.setTitle("X: 0 , Y: 0");
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide small samples of code, configuration files, and anything else that will help us diagnose your problem.  thanks!

Comment: Here is some of the code. Not sure why the code is not color coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. In the Export dialog box, another project was automatically selected under Launch Configuration - not the project I right-clicked upon.